# Automatically transfer a summed total to another cell in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: automation, data-transfer

Example:   cell a24 is the sum of (a1:a23).  I would like a24 to automatically populate cell c1 as part of another calculation
This seems do-able.  Can anyone help?
Thanks,
flyrod

Comment: Easily, in a number of ways. For example, just enter **=A24** in cell C1.

Answer (score 0):

Just enter in C1 =A24 and it should fill in the data. If for some strange reason that doesn't work you could just insert a sum in C1 that is just the sum of a24, SUM(A24), that way it just takes A24, and adds nothing, so you get exactly what A24 was equal to. Alternatively, you could just add another sum in C1 that adds up A1:A23 it should achieve the same thing.

Comment: you don't need a dummy `SUM()` around it, you can just use `=A24`. Or embed it into any other formula you want to use there